# Numpy.savetxt to save string and float in the meantime and maintain the precision of the float

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I wrote a python script,

```
import numpy

a = 8.3
b = 8.29993191
c = abs(a - b)
print c
d = numpy.array(c)
e = ['value']
f = numpy.vstack((e, d))
print f
g = ['valuesssssssssssss']
h = numpy.vstack((g, d))
print h

numpy.savetxt('2k.csv', f, '%s', delimiter = ',')
```

And here's the output,

```
6.8090000001e-05
[['value']
 ['6.809']]
[['valuesssssssssssss']
 ['6.8090000001e-05']]
```

Apparently, the precision of the float I want to save into the csv file depends on the length of the string, because I need to use '%s' to save string and float simultaneously.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

On this line:

```
f = numpy.vstack((e, d))
```

`vstack`is coercing the type of `d` to the type of `e`. You can check this by printing `f.dtype`.

You should instead build `f` like this

```
f = np.zeros(1,dtype=('|S5, float64'))
f[0] = e[0],d
```

Refer to the docs on structured arrays specifically to [this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html#defining-structured-arrays) paragraph, if you don't understand the line above.

At the time of printing `f`, you can choose a different format specifier. With `15` digits and scientific notation you can go for:

```
np.savetxt('2k.csv', f, fmt = ('%s','%.15e'),delimiter = ',')
```

The resulting file is

```
# cat 2k.csv
value,6.809000000096432e-05
```

To save the number under the string, use a custom format for `savetxt`:

```
np.savetxt('2k.csv', f, fmt = '%s\n%.15e')
```

which outputs:

```
# cat 2k.csv
value
6.809000000096432e-05
```

Comment: I tried your code, numpy.savetxt('2k.csv', f, fmt = ('%s','%.15e'),delimiter = ','), but got this error, AttributeError: fmt has wrong shape.  ('%s', '%.15e')

Comment: The above code works. I have edited the answer to exactly match the step to initialize `f`. Does it work now?

Comment: Thank you, your code did work, but the result is not what I want, that is, the float is **under** the string.